# Handlebars not compliling correctly Claims I do not pass a string

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

What have I done wrong in trying to use Handlebars here?

**HTML**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.min.js"></script>



</script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/1.0.0/handlebars.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="_conv_logo_login_container">

  </div>
</body>
</html>

  <script  type="text/x-handlebars-template" id="tools_links_template">

  <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

    {{#tools_links}}

     <li>

       <a id="{{id}}" href="{{href}}">{{human_readable}}</a>

     </li>

    {{/tools_links}}


  </ul>
```

**JS**

```
var data = {
    "tools_links": [
        {
            "id": "assignments",
            "human_readable_report": "Assignments",
            "href": "site.com/assignments",
            "attrs": {
                "data-order": 1
            },
            "submenu": ""
        },
        {
            "id": "reporting",
            "human_readable": "Reporting",
            "href": "site.com/reporting",
            "attrs": {
                "data-order": 2
            },
            "submenu": ""
        }
    ]
};


var source   = $("#tools_links_template").html();
var template = Handlebars.compile(source);

$("._conv_logo_login_container").html(template(data));
```

I keep receiving the error:

```
Uncaught Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined
```

I have tried `{{#with tools_links}}` and simply `{{items}}`.

[JSBIN](http://jsbin.com/hocivecafe/1/edit)

Comment: Should include the HTML in the question too - that's where the template is.

Comment: Edited it. The HTML is in the jsbin, but the link is hard to notice.. not much contrast between the links on SO and text.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two Problems:

1. Your template is not inside of the `<html></html>` tags. Put the template `<script>` tag inside of the `<head>` or at the bottom of the `<body>`.
2. Your template does not have an ending `</script>` tag.

jQuery searches for elements within the `<head>` and `<body>`, not within all of the text of an HTML file.